# Argument principle and Riemann hypothesis

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-zeta, riemann-hypothesis

Argument principle states:

> If $f$ is a meromorphic function inside and on some closed contour $C$, **and $f$ has no zeros or poles on $C$**, then
> $$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_C \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}\,dz=Z-P$$
> where $Z$ and $P$ denote the number of zeros and poles in $C$ (counting multiplicity).

The central part of numerically verifying the Riemann hypothesis is using the argument principle to count the number of zeros of the Riemann zeta function in a given region.

But there is one problem: When choosing the contour, how do we know that $\zeta$ has **no zeros on the contour**? We don't know whether a region is zero-free in advance, so how should we choose the contour?

My idea was that the imaginary parts of the zeros are all irrational, so we just choose a rational number, but it turns out that we actually don't know if the imaginary parts are irrational.

Comment: We... don't. That's why we are counting zeros, to find where they are. So perturb $C$ a bit and see if the answer changes.

Comment: @prets What if I perturb it in such a way that the contour lands on a zero

Comment: @prets I imagine that it is somehow possible to **know** that the contour doesn't land on a zero if there are people claiming that they **proved** the Riemann hypothesis up to a given height. They somehow have to prove that the assumptions of the argument principle are indeed satisfied in order to use that principle.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding how the argument principle is used here; generally one computes theoretically $N(T)$ using it for $\xi'/\xi$ on a special curve; the book  by Edwards on page 128 has the specific way used by Backlund to count the number of zeroes up to height $200$ though now there are of course many refinements; then one counts the zeroes on $\Re s =1/2$ by counting changes of sign of the Hardy $Z$ function (real on the critical line) with the Riemann Siegel formula which is very accurate and compares with the theoretical number above; so far they have been always equal

Comment: @Conrad Can one prove that $\zeta$ has no zeros for a given $\Im s=\text{constant}$ *before* using the argument principle?

Comment: that is not needed since one takes such an $s$ by definition (near enough $T$) - again look up Edwards book to see how is done; everything is theoretical and one comes up with a formula for $N(T)$ from stuff about $\Gamma$ essentially; then one actually estimates the number of zeroes on the critical line with Riemann Siegel;

Comment: $N(T)$ is an integer function that is constant in-between zeroes and jumps by the multiplicity there, so the stuff that comes from $\Gamma$ and is well known is enough to compute it at least for the values of $T$ amenable to such so far; it is possible that for $T$ very large on the order of $10^{10^{500}}$ say - in other words where $\log \log T$ is not very small there may be oscillation that is more difficult to control, but before that range $N(T)$ is essentially the one coming from the $\Gamma$ factors so the integer part of a known and easy to estimate function

Comment: @Conrad In Edwards' book, I see "it is assumed that $T$ is such that there are no roots on the line $\operatorname{Im}s=T$." Then Backlund observed that "if it can be shown that $\operatorname{Re}\zeta$ is never zero on $C$ [...]"; showing that it doesn't vanish on $C$ takes a bit of work, doesn't it?

Comment: @Conrad When you wrote "one takes such an $s$ by definition (near enough 
$T$)": one still has to *find* a $T$ such that zeta is nonzero on $\Im s=T$?

Comment: the zeroes of $\zeta$ are countable - in any finite region for $T$ they are finite, so their ordinates are too, hence there always exist non zero ordinates near any $T$; people worked a lot on this topic and within computational ranges there are very good estimates of $N(T)$ from theory as the only unknown term ($S(T)$ or essentially the argument of zeta) is very small there (I think highest known value has absolute value between $3$ and $4$ though it is known that $S$ unbounded); the computational trickier part is estimating the zeroes on the line using Riemann Siegel and variants

Comment: @Conrad For example, how can I show that $\Im (\xi (30i+x))$ is nonzero for $0\le x\le 1$?

Comment: you use the table of zeroes of zeta and note that there is no zero on that line

Comment: @Conrad Well, that's the problem. I want to make a table of zeta zeros by using that result. I want to avoid circular arguments.

Comment: @Conrad Or, to put it differently: when making the table, how does one even *know* that $\Im (\xi (30i+x))$ is non-zero for $0\le x\le 1$? Is there a general method for proving such statements?

Comment: one shows using theory that up $T=31$ say there are $4$ zeroes and then using Riemann Siegel one shows that on the critical line the Hardy function $Z$ has $4$ changes of sign which can be estimated up to as many decimals as your computing power allows, so for example up to $2$ decimals they are at $14.13, 21.02, 25.01, 32.42$ so those must indeed the only zeroes up to $T=31$ hence there is no zero with $T=30$; for a list of the first 100 zeroes estimated to over $1000$ digits see http://www.plouffe.fr/simon/constants/zeta100.html

Comment: "one shows using theory that up $T=31$ say there are $4$ zeros": this is exactly what I'm interested in. I tried using the argument principle, but it requires that $\xi$ be non-zero on the contour which I don't know how to prove (I'm **not** intersted in someone else's tables, I want to make my own table as a fun exercise)

Comment: I am not really sure we are on the same page; the formula for $N(T)=\frac{T}{2\pi}\log \frac{T}{2\pi}-\frac{T}{2\pi}+7/8+S(T)+E(T)$ where $E(T)=O(1/T)$ with asymptotics in inverse powers of $T$ known, and $S(T)=\frac {1}{\pi}\arg \zeta (1/2+it)$ is proven in many places (eg Titchmarsh, Edwards); for estimating $S(T)$ for $T$ relatively big (millions), the method of Turing in the 1950's using just general theory from Littlewood and showing that $S(T)$ is negligible there so the exact formula above gives $N(T)$ - see Edwards p 175

Comment: @Conrad So we just choose $T$ such that $S(T)$ is negligible and then we use $N(T)=T/(2\pi)\cdots$ which will give the number of zeros?

Comment: @Conrad That's weird, everyone on MSE was saying that they count the zeta zeros by argument principle together with the sign changes of Riemann–Siegel Z. I didn't really appreciate the argument principle because of the need of showing that $\xi$ doesn't vanish on the contour. But as you say, perhaps a different formula is used for counting the zeros. Thanks.

Comment: The method is correct - the argument principle gives the formula above ($N(T)=$ known +$S(T)$) and then various things are used to estimate $S(T)$ and for example it is shown to be small even when $T$ is fairly large, so one can get $N(T)$ just by the known term; then one uses Riemann Siegel to count the zeroes on the line by sign changes and shows they are exactly same; note that sometimes one only needs to estimate $N(T)$ above as if then one gets that estimate as zeroes on the critical line by sign changes, one is done

Comment: @Conrad And what is $\operatorname{arg}$ in $S(T)=\frac{1}{\pi}\operatorname{arg}\zeta(1/2+it)$? Is it the principal complex argument or something else?

Comment: @Conrad And is the formula $N(T)=$ known $+S(T)$ valid even if $T$ is an imaginary part of a zeta zero?

Comment: $S(T)$ is defined by analytic continuation starting at $s=2$ and going vertical at $2+iT$ and horizontal to $1/2+iT$ then - first we assume $T$ is not an ordinate of a zero and then we define both $N,S$ at an ordinate either by the upper limit $N(T^+), S(T^+)$ or by the average below and above - various authors use either but it doesn't really matter as those are only countable points where both $N,S$ jump by same integer (expected to be $1$ of course always as all roots of RZ are expected simple)

Comment: @Conrad So when computing $N(T^+)$ you choose small $h$ in $N(T+h)$ but how can you be sure that the $h$ you choose doesn't land you on a zeta zero? And how small does $h$ have to be?

Comment: The zeroes are discrete so if $T$ is an ordinate, there is a small neighborhood of it where there is no ordinate hence for all $h$ small enough $T \pm h$ is not an ordinate; not sure if there are known inferior bounds for the distance between zero ordinates but on average since there are about $c\log T$ zeroes within $1$, the spacing should be about $c/\log T$ so usually $h<< 1/\log T$ on average

Comment: @Conrad Just one last question: **Without a precomputed table**, how would one prove, for example, that $\Im (\xi (30i+x))$ is non-zero for all $0\le x\le 1$?

Comment: Would use Wolfram alpha at a few values of $\sigma$ and see what approximation formulas they use (there are a quite a few such, though their rate of convergence differs, so not sure in general which is best - on the critical line Riemann Siegel is very good but that may be because of symmetry so its analogue for $\sigma \ne 1/2$, the AFE may be worse than say using eta and truncating)

Comment: @Conrad But using a few values of $\sigma$ isn't a mathematical proof, one has to prove it for **all** $\sigma \in (0,1)$. I guess it takes some work, but it can be done?

Comment: @Conrad In Edwards' book, p. 129, I see for example that one proves that $\Re \zeta\ne 0$ on the segment from $3/2+ig_{137}$ to $1/2+ig_{137}$. Can their method of proof be generalized?

Comment: My suggestion refers to how Wolfram alpha estimates the result (uses various formulas) and maybe see if one such formula can then be used for all $\sigma$; personally I do not really have that much interest in these kind of computations as once they are done and lists of zeroes generated that's that so to speak - because of universality zeta will behave very random at least between $1/2$ and $1$;